# Chrome 58+(вета) перестал работать с самоподписанными сертификатами

Tags: google-chrome, сертификат

сертификаты устанавливаются без проблем, но при подключении он их не видит/непонимает или ещё что.   в сертификате - SHA256. FF с этим сертификатом работает. есть какая-нибудь информация о такой подлянке?

Answer (score 1):

Доменное имя больше не сверяется с `commonName`. Теперь всегда требуется наличие в сертификате `subjectAltName` с хотя бы одним значением, в котором указан ваш домен:
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/topic/security-dev/IGT2fLJrAeo/discussion

Comment: разжуй немного подробнее.... т.е. теперь нет такого как самоподписанные? если мне надо чисто для внутренних нужд, без всякого другого-  я не могу как раньше?

Comment: Есть. Просто нужно генерировать сертификаты с полем subjectAltName - как самоподписанные, так и подписываемые центром сертификации. Обычно, для упрощения, самоподписаные сертификаты генерируют без него, только с commonName - теперь Google Chrome такие сертификаты не считает корректными - в ближайшем будущем такое поведение вероятно переймут и другие браузеры. Как и чем вы генерируете сертификат, к сожалению, я не знаю.

Comment: пока пользовался http://portecle.sourceforge.net/ , но, видимо, она устарела. такого поля subjectAltName я там не нашёл. Есть предложения чем можно сейчас сгенерить ? зарегистрированного домена нет. я в host прописывал типа xx.xx и Ip. для разработки и для небольшой конторы хватало такой секрктности.